# how do i uninstall a PPA?

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Do I uninstall PPAs through synaptic just like I would a "default" application? or do I need to do different/additional steps?